# "buttonImportIcon" syntax for Javascript PDF code

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am attempting to import an icon into a button form field, using a page from a separate PDF file. I need to use other pages rather than just the first page of the document and I have tried to accomplish this by specifying "nPage" in the syntax. Regardless of this input, the icon only imports the first page of the document. Below is the syntax that I currently have:

this.getField("test").buttonImportIcon({
    cPath: "Z:/tempDWGs.pdf",
    nPage: 4
});

Does anyone know why the code above is using page '0' from the source document and not page '4'? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the software specific coding engine that was not processing the command correctly. The above code is correct and should work as intended.